# How do I view a website in my desktop browser from a web app running in server in a VM on my desktop?

Tags: web-applications, virtualbox, virtual-server

I am running Ubuntu on my workstation, and headless Ubuntu Server in VirtualBox on this same workstation.

I'd like to write a web app and deploy it on Ubuntu Server in the VM, then load it in a web browser on my workstation.

Is this possible, and if so how?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the [answer](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1235218&highlight=virtualbox+web+server):  Change the Virtual Box -> Settings (for the guest OS) -> Network -> Attached to: Bridged Adapter.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep NAT, you can use port forwarding, [see this](http://mydebian.blogdns.org/?p=148), exchange the ports to 80 and 8888 (or something) to do the same for HTTP.